# How can values from one object be used to edit those of another object?

Tags: javascript, object

### Explanation of Layout/Format:

In a game which I am coding, there are different resources. Upgrades to items cost varying amounts of these resources, although most cost only 2 or 3 resource types. As each of the several hundred resource types have multiple parameters (quantity, flavour text, etc.), I decided that it would be most sensible to create the data pertaining to these resources via objects. The layout that I finally decided upon is as follows (`$` denotes the root game object):

```
$.resources.genericResource = {

    resource1: {

        amount: 0,
        earnt: 0,
        flavourText: "Generic flavour text"

    }
    resource2: {

        amount: 0,
        earnt: 0,
        flavourText: "Not generic flavour text"

    }
    resource42: {

        amount: 0,
        earnt: 0,
        flavourText: "The answer to life, the Universe, and everything" //Possibly...

    }

}
```

Every resource has an `amount` integer variable, which (as the name probably suggests) denotes the quantity of each resource currently owned.

Each purchasable item (upgrade, building, etc.) has a base cost of a number of resources (as well as a few other things). As is so, this is also denoted via an object:

```
$.upgrades.genericUpgrade.baseCost = {

    resource1: 7,
    resource2: 1,
    resource42: Math.PI

}
```

**Note that both of these will be initialised more intelligently than has been detailed here - this is just an example to show the format that will be used.**

### Reason for Layout/Format Requirement:

Now, these need to be objects as opposed to arrays, because there is extra data associated with each of the resources - and the game will continue to be updated with new resources (so save-file problems could arise with index editing). However, instead of the `baseCost` for every purchasable item containing a key for every resource (for which the values would mostly be zeros), I would like to simply have it contain only the values different from zero. This would greatly increase neatness, ease of updating, file size and my sanity to no end.

### My Problem:

Quite simply: I have absolutely no idea how to create a loop which, given the `baseCost` object, returns the values of the related `$.resources` object , due to the fact that objects, unlike arrays, are non-indexable. I would also need to edit the `$.resources` value after a successful purchase, although that would be much easier given the names of the pertinent keys, as a simple `for` loop with

```
$.resources[resource].amount -= cost;
```

for each of the resources.

*TL;DR: I don't know how to iterate upon two separate objects given the key names from one of them.*

### Possible Solutions (or attempts/beginnings at thus) by myself:

Before I go any further, I will firstly make a couple of helper variables to reference the `baseCost` and `$.resources` objects, as this will greatly reduce the code length (in the real code the former would only reference the `$.upgrades` object):

```
var $u = $.upgrades.genericUpgrade.baseCost;
var $r = $.resources;
```

I began by thinking through how the input would be gained - firstly the number of keys for `$.upgrades.genericUpgrade.baseCost` would need to be ascertained. Simple enough - just do something similar to the following:

```
var keys = Object.keys($u);
var keyQuantity = keys.length;
```

The previous code snippet contains yet another useful variable: an array containing the key names as strings. This would be useful for the final replacement, but firstly we need a `for` loop within which the validity of a purchase would be found (aka. whether or not it is too expensive):

```
var keysIndex;
for (i = 0; i < keyQuantity; i++) {

    keysIndex = keys[i];

    //Is the resource cost greater than the amount of the resource owned?
    if ($u[keysIndex] > $r[keysIndex]) { 

        //Code to either break out of the loop, return false, or something similar

    }

}
```

This is almost complete: all that is required now is to negate the cost if the item is not too expensive, and to put all of the code together. Then we get the following:

```
function purchaseUpgrade(upgrade) {

    var $u = $.upgrades[upgrade].baseCost;
    var $r = $.resources;

    var keys = Object.keys($u);
    var keyQuantity = keys.length;

    //Helper variable to assist with key referencing:
    var keysIndex;

    //Boolean to decide whether or not a purchase is valid
    var isValid = true;

    //Check for all resources in $u:
    for (i = 0; i < keyQuantity; i++) {

        keysIndex = keys[i];

        //Is the resource cost greater than the amount of the resource owned?
        if ($u[keysIndex] > $r[keysIndex].amount) { 

            //Invalidate the purchase
            isValid = false;

            //As no more permutations are necessary, break the loop:
            break;

        }

    }

    //If all resource costs are lesser than the owned resources, do the following:
    if (isValid === true) {

        for (i = 0; i < keyQuantity; i++) {

            keysIndex = keys[i];
            $r[keysIndex].amount -= $u[keysIndex];

        }

        $.upgrades[upgrade].owned += 1;

    }

}
```

The function can be called by `purchaseUpgrade("nameOfUpgrade")`.

### Wrapping up

I now realise that I have solved this problem whilst writing it out... Still, as there are no apparent similar questions on StackOverflow, I have still decided to post this, as it may come in useful for someone else at some point. However, if anyone thinks that they have a better/more efficient answer, feel free to post it - in that case, I would select it as 'best answer'.